# CSS :x scroll limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my code,

```
#mainDiv {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

#leftPanel {
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
   padding-left: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 350px;
}``


#rightPanel {
    margin-left: 390px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

As the name suggest inside maindiv I have placed left and right panels. The left panel has the unordered list of hrefs and right panel displays the detailed info about the link clicked on left.

The problem now is when I x-scroll the rightpanel the content overlaps with the content of left panel(since margin-left of right panel is 390px;). How can I limit x-scroll ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to make the question a bit more clear,. and what you mean by limiting x-scroll

Answer (score 0):

In `#right panel`, add `overflow-x:scroll`

Please do check [reference to overflow-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) for more choices.
When it is overflowing to the outer side of a block, overflow is set to visible, which is the default value of overflow property.